# Load django template dynamically

Tags: django, django-templates

I've 2 section in my screen. Left section is for showing tabs and right is for displaying that tab template(as shown in screenshot). I'm not able to understand how to load different templates when I click these tabs

For example, when I click change password, I should be able to load change_password.html template

This is by far I've tried with code.

```
 <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home" id="home" {% with section='home'%}{% endwith %}><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Home</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#change_password" id="change_password" {% with section='change_password'%}{% endwith %}><i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Change Password</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bookings" id="bookings" {% with section='bookings'%}{% endwith %}><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true" ></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Bookings</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#settings" id="settings" {% with section='settings'%}{% endwith %}><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Settings</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I've tried to use with but no luck.

I've just started with django, so if anything is missed let me know. Thanks for your help!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqz32.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're attempting is not possible. If you don't want a page reload upon clicking on a tab, you need to use Javascript to dynamically show/hide elements. If page reload is acceptable, you can create different views for each tab, each view rendering a different html file.

You can use the Django include tag to render another template with the current context. E.g. `{% include "foo/bar.html" %}` (see documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include)). But this will not solve your problem of displaying different content upon clicking on a tab.