# Django templates - pass data outside for loop

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have a table of users and one table data is a button that opens up a modal, I am including the modal in the tamplate with the `include` tag. How do I pass the user from the row in which the button was clicked to the include tag?

```
{% for user in users %}
<tr>
 <td>
   <button class="btn btn-lg device-select-button">
          <span>Select Device</span>
   </button>
 </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

{% include 'app/admin/users/device_select_modal.html' user={{add here user}} %}
```

In other implementation I have generated a modal for each row, and it works but slow, So I want to reimplement that

Comment: I think you'll need JavaScript to do that. AFAIk the template is built only once when you load the page, there's no way to tell it to wait for the user to click. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165313/load-django-template-dynamically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be to store the required data you want to pass to the modal as `html data attribute`

```
<button data-id={{ user.id }} data-name="{{ user.name }}" class="btn btn-lg device-select-button">
```

And in your implementation of the modal you can pass data using the `onclick` attribute of the button with some javascript.

```
<button onclick="yourFunctionThatOpensModal(this.getAttribute('data-name'), this.getAttribute('data-id'))"  data-id={{ user.id }} data-name="{{ user.name }}" class="btn btn-lg device-select-button">
```